# Django KeyError when getting an object with a keyword for a field name

Tags: django

I wish to get an object in the following fashion:

```
Collection.objects.get(name='name', type='library', owner=owner, parent=parent)
```

Unfortunately `type` is a keyword as thus creates the following error:

```
KeyError at /forms/create_library
type
```

Is there a way to disambiguate the meaning of the word `type` to allow me to specify a field of that name?

Comment: This problem is probably better fixed by renaming the `type` field to something that is not a reserved word.

Comment: Yes you are quite right, for future reference is there a way to do what I am atempting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested:

```
Collection.objects.filter(
    name__exact='name', 
    type__exact='library', 
    owner__exact=owner, 
    parent__exact=parent)
```

Query docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Also consider naming your field differently, mainly not with the same name as a builtin.

Comment: This does not seem to resolve the error, but as everyone has mentioned I will change the name of the field name to a more suitable choice.

Answer (score 0):

OK it turns out the problem was elsewhere. I was doing this in a form and thus using the `self.cleaned_data` dictionary of input values.

I was attempting to retrieve `self.cleaned_data['type']` where in my previous simplification I stated the string 'library'. This was not in fact in the cleaned data of the form and thus threw a `KeyError`.